# Iterating through array of objects react-native

Tags: react-native, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

I have a response like

```
   {
   "payload":{
      "count":158,
      "transactionList":[
         {
            "_id":2410787,
            "chnl":"Mobile",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1005",
            "event_name":"1005",
            "interface":{
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "system":"EI-Platform",
               "event":1005,
               "src_system_name":"SNOC",
               "undefined":"9842012345"
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Request-Type",
            "src":"i",
            "status":152,
            "status_track":[
               {
                  "status":103,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "status":152,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410787,
            "tz":"20201012165651",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z"
            },
            "utype":730,
            "status_name":"Completed",
            "status_key":"status_2",
            "event_description":"Bolt On/Top Up"
         },
         {
            "_id":2410786,
            "chnl":"Web",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1004",
            "event_name":"1004",
            "interface":{
               "amount":120,
               "customerName":"David Smith",
               "event":1004,
               "totalAmount":120,
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "payment_details":{
                  "cash_mode":{
                     "status":111,
                     "cash":"120"
                  }
               },
               "account_no":11241212
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "payment_status":111,
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Create",
            "src":"i",
            "status":152,
            "status_track":[
               {
                  "status":103,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "status":152,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410786,
            "tz":"20201010120230",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z"
            },
            "utype":1,
            "status_name":"Completed",
            "status_key":"status_2",
            "event_description":"Bill Payment"
         },
         {
            "_id":2410762,
            "chnl":"Web",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.631Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1001",
            "event_name":"1001",
            "interface":{
               "pcardno":"8944110000000100017",
               "doc_tran_value":"",
               "p_lname":"Sharma",
               "product_id":"PAYG01",
               "p_fname":"Rakesh",
               "msisdn":"7999990099",
               "zipcode":"9090",
               "state":"50054",
               "lastname":"Sharma",
               "firstname":"Rakesh",
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "country":"50052",
               "system":"EI-Platform",
               "title":"50092",
               "icc":"80990",
               "phoneNumber":"9709607195",
               "address":"kormangla",
               "email":"no@no.com",
               "event":1001,
               "dob":"02-Sep-2002"
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "pending_at":"Head Of Sales",
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Create",
            "src":"i",
            "status":103,
            "status_track":[],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410762,
            "tz":"20200922111540",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.875Z"
            },
            "utype":1,
            "status_name":"In Progress",
            "status_key":"status_1",
            "event_description":"Prepaid Form"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need an array which contains `event_description` and `count` i.e., `event_description` is from `transactionsList` and `count` is number of occurrences based on `event_description` in transactionsList. Please check the following code which I have tried, but it didn't worked. Can you please help me.

```
      var transactionList = response.payload.transactionList
      var events = []
      for (const transaction in transactionList) {
        let existedIndex = events.findIndex(({event}) => event['event_description'] == transaction['event_description'])
        if (existedIndex && existedIndex >= 0) {
          events[existedIndex]['count'] = events[existedIndex]['count'] + 1
        } else {
          let newEvent = { 'event_description': transaction['event_description'], 'count': 1 }
          events.push(newEvent);
        }
      }
```

The resultant array should contain objects, and every object has two keys, one is `count` which is the number of occurrences of `event-description` and another one `event_description` itself.

Comment: update `let existedIndex = events.findIndex(({event}) => event['event_description'] == transaction['event_description'])` to `let existedIndex = events.findIndex((event) => event['event_description'] == transaction['event_description'])`

Comment: @SaachiTech, can you please try it fully and help me, because I'm new to `react-native`. I tried as per your hint, but I'm not  getting expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code block

```
var transactionList = response.payload.transactionList
var events = []
transactionList.forEach((transaction, index)=>{
  let existedIndex = events.findIndex((event) => event.event_description === transaction.event_description)
  if (existedIndex >= 0) {
    events[existedIndex].count = events[existedIndex].count + 1
  } else {
    let newEvent = { 'event_description': transaction.event_description, 'count': 1 }
    events.push(newEvent);
  }
})
console.log(events)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with indexes when you need to work with objects.
You need to use `for of` not `for in`
This is the updated code:

```
  var transactionList = response.payload.transactionList;
  var events = [];
  for (const transaction of transactionList) {
    let existedIndex = events.findIndex(
      ({ event }) =>
        event && // a little test because sometime it returns undifined
        event["event_description"] &&
        event["event_description"] == transaction["event_description"]
    );
    if (existedIndex && existedIndex >= 0) {
      events[existedIndex]["count"] = events[existedIndex]["count"] + 1;
    } else {
      let newEvent = {
        event_description: transaction["event_description"],
        count: 1,
      };
      events.push(newEvent);
    }
  }
```

And here's a complete snippet where I changed the JSON to an object so you can test it without using RN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const response = {
        payload: {
          count: 158,
          transactionList: [
            {
              _id: 2410787,
              chnl: "Mobile",
              crtd_by: 30001,
              crtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z",
              },
              event_id: "1005",
              event_name: "1005",
              interface: {
                deviceInfo: {
                  webOrMobile: "web",
                },
                system: "EI-Platform",
                event: 1005,
                src_system_name: "SNOC",
                undefined: "9842012345",
              },
              locale: "en",
              nodeid: 20,
              org_id: 20,
              org_type: 5,
              pwd: "KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
              rqst: "Request-Type",
              src: "i",
              status: 152,
              status_track: [
                {
                  status: 103,
                  updtd_dt: {
                    $date: "2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z",
                  },
                },
                {
                  status: 152,
                  updtd_dt: {
                    $date: "2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z",
                  },
                },
              ],
              timezoneOffset: -330,
              transaction_id: 2410787,
              tz: "20201012165651",
              uid: 30001,
              uname: "EIADMIN",
              updtd_by: 30001,
              updtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z",
              },
              utype: 730,
              status_name: "Completed",
              status_key: "status_2",
              event_description: "Bolt On/Top Up",
            },
            {
              _id: 2410786,
              chnl: "Web",
              crtd_by: 30001,
              crtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z",
              },
              event_id: "1004",
              event_name: "1004",
              interface: {
                amount: 120,
                customerName: "David Smith",
                event: 1004,
                totalAmount: 120,
                deviceInfo: {
                  webOrMobile: "web",
                },
                payment_details: {
                  cash_mode: {
                    status: 111,
                    cash: "120",
                  },
                },
                account_no: 11241212,
              },
              locale: "en",
              nodeid: 20,
              org_id: 20,
              org_type: 5,
              payment_status: 111,
              pwd: "KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
              rqst: "Create",
              src: "i",
              status: 152,
              status_track: [
                {
                  status: 103,
                  updtd_dt: {
                    $date: "2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z",
                  },
                },
                {
                  status: 152,
                  updtd_dt: {
                    $date: "2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z",
                  },
                },
              ],
              timezoneOffset: -330,
              transaction_id: 2410786,
              tz: "20201010120230",
              uid: 30001,
              uname: "EIADMIN",
              updtd_by: 30001,
              updtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z",
              },
              utype: 1,
              status_name: "Completed",
              status_key: "status_2",
              event_description: "Bill Payment",
            },
            {
              _id: 2410762,
              chnl: "Web",
              crtd_by: 30001,
              crtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-09-22T11:15:40.631Z",
              },
              event_id: "1001",
              event_name: "1001",
              interface: {
                pcardno: "8944110000000100017",
                doc_tran_value: "",
                p_lname: "Sharma",
                product_id: "PAYG01",
                p_fname: "Rakesh",
                msisdn: "7999990099",
                zipcode: "9090",
                state: "50054",
                lastname: "Sharma",
                firstname: "Rakesh",
                deviceInfo: {
                  webOrMobile: "web",
                },
                country: "50052",
                system: "EI-Platform",
                title: "50092",
                icc: "80990",
                phoneNumber: "9709607195",
                address: "kormangla",
                email: "no@no.com",
                event: 1001,
                dob: "02-Sep-2002",
              },
              locale: "en",
              nodeid: 20,
              org_id: 20,
              org_type: 5,
              pending_at: "Head Of Sales",
              pwd: "KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
              rqst: "Create",
              src: "i",
              status: 103,
              status_track: [],
              timezoneOffset: -330,
              transaction_id: 2410762,
              tz: "20200922111540",
              uid: 30001,
              uname: "EIADMIN",
              updtd_by: 30001,
              updtd_dt: {
                $date: "2020-09-22T11:15:40.875Z",
              },
              utype: 1,
              status_name: "In Progress",
              status_key: "status_1",
              event_description: "Prepaid Form",
            },
          ],
        },
      };

      var transactionList = response.payload.transactionList;
      var events = [];
      for (const transaction of transactionList) {
        let existedIndex;
        existedIndex = events.findIndex(
          ({ event }) =>
            event &&
            event["event_description"] &&
            event["event_description"] == transaction["event_description"]
        );
        if (existedIndex && existedIndex >= 0) {
          events[existedIndex]["count"] = events[existedIndex]["count"] + 1;
        } else {
          let newEvent = {
            event_description: transaction["event_description"],
            count: 1,
          };
          events.push(newEvent);
        }
      }
      console.log(events);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (existedIndex && existedIndex >= 0) {` this wont work when existedIndex is 0.

Comment: Because it's in the code I assume that it's the logic he needs. Maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array reduce like this

```js
const data= {
   "payload":{
      "count":158,
      "transactionList":[
         {
            "_id":2410787,
            "chnl":"Mobile",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1005",
            "event_name":"1005",
            "interface":{
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "system":"EI-Platform",
               "event":1005,
               "src_system_name":"SNOC",
               "undefined":"9842012345"
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Request-Type",
            "src":"i",
            "status":152,
            "status_track":[
               {
                  "status":103,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.243Z"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "status":152,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410787,
            "tz":"20201012165651",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-12T11:26:52.452Z"
            },
            "utype":730,
            "status_name":"Completed",
            "status_key":"status_2",
            "event_description":"Bolt On/Top Up"
         },
         {
            "_id":2410786,
            "chnl":"Web",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1004",
            "event_name":"1004",
            "interface":{
               "amount":120,
               "customerName":"David Smith",
               "event":1004,
               "totalAmount":120,
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "payment_details":{
                  "cash_mode":{
                     "status":111,
                     "cash":"120"
                  }
               },
               "account_no":11241212
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "payment_status":111,
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Create",
            "src":"i",
            "status":152,
            "status_track":[
               {
                  "status":103,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.069Z"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "status":152,
                  "updtd_dt":{
                     "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410786,
            "tz":"20201010120230",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-10-10T12:02:32.319Z"
            },
            "utype":1,
            "status_name":"Completed",
            "status_key":"status_2",
            "event_description":"Bill Payment"
         },
         {
            "_id":2410762,
            "chnl":"Web",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.631Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1001",
            "event_name":"1001",
            "interface":{
               "pcardno":"8944110000000100017",
               "doc_tran_value":"",
               "p_lname":"Sharma",
               "product_id":"PAYG01",
               "p_fname":"Rakesh",
               "msisdn":"7999990099",
               "zipcode":"9090",
               "state":"50054",
               "lastname":"Sharma",
               "firstname":"Rakesh",
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "country":"50052",
               "system":"EI-Platform",
               "title":"50092",
               "icc":"80990",
               "phoneNumber":"9709607195",
               "address":"kormangla",
               "email":"no@no.com",
               "event":1001,
               "dob":"02-Sep-2002"
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "pending_at":"Head Of Sales",
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Create",
            "src":"i",
            "status":103,
            "status_track":[],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410762,
            "tz":"20200922111540",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.875Z"
            },
            "utype":1,
            "status_name":"In Progress",
            "status_key":"status_1",
            "event_description":"Prepaid Form"
         },
         {
            "_id":2410762,
            "chnl":"Web",
            "crtd_by":30001,
            "crtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.631Z"
            },
            "event_id":"1001",
            "event_name":"1001",
            "interface":{
               "pcardno":"8944110000000100017",
               "doc_tran_value":"",
               "p_lname":"Sharma",
               "product_id":"PAYG01",
               "p_fname":"Rakesh",
               "msisdn":"7999990099",
               "zipcode":"9090",
               "state":"50054",
               "lastname":"Sharma",
               "firstname":"Rakesh",
               "deviceInfo":{
                  "webOrMobile":"web"
               },
               "country":"50052",
               "system":"EI-Platform",
               "title":"50092",
               "icc":"80990",
               "phoneNumber":"9709607195",
               "address":"kormangla",
               "email":"no@no.com",
               "event":1001,
               "dob":"02-Sep-2002"
            },
            "locale":"en",
            "nodeid":20,
            "org_id":20,
            "org_type":5,
            "pending_at":"Head Of Sales",
            "pwd":"KpR8Vp8SMRWPncdaBwMLwnsWh2E1JfoPnTE1rozmc3s=",
            "rqst":"Create",
            "src":"i",
            "status":103,
            "status_track":[],
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "transaction_id":2410762,
            "tz":"20200922111540",
            "uid":30001,
            "uname":"EIADMIN",
            "updtd_by":30001,
            "updtd_dt":{
               "$date":"2020-09-22T11:15:40.875Z"
            },
            "utype":1,
            "status_name":"In Progress",
            "status_key":"status_1",
            "event_description":"Prepaid Form"
         }
      ]
   }
};

const reducer = (acc, cur) => {
  const item = acc.find((x) => x['event_description'] === cur['event_description']);
  if (item) {
    item.count++;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      event_description: cur.event_description,
      count:1
    });
  }
  return acc;
};

console.log(data.payload.transactionList.reduce(reducer,[]))
```